# Syntax Command Error

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

An error "The syntax of command is incorrect" always appears every time I'm going to run this batch file. I can't seem to figure out which part of the script is causing this error. Any idea?

```
rem Process all *.tif files in input path
pushd "%in_path%"
for %%a in (*.tif) do (
   set "fileName=%%a"
   rem If the YearDay in this file is the same of previous one
   if "!fileName:~1,7!" equ "!yearDay!" (
      rem Join this filename to previous list
      set "fileList=!fileList!!fileName! "
      set /A numFiles+=1
   ) else (
      rem Merge the files in the list if there are more than 3, in the out_path leaving only TYYYYDDD.L2_LAC.Tera.tif
      if !numFiles! gtr 3 (
         gdal_merge.py -n 0 -a_nodata -32767 -of GTiff -o %out_path%\T!yearDay!.L2_LAC.Tera.tif !fileList!
         rem Move processed files to a different directory
         set "fileList=!fileList:~0,-1!"
         move !fileList: =,! "%proc_path%"
      )
      rem And start a new YearDay and fileList
      set "yearDay=!fileName:~1,7!"
      set "fileList=!fileName! "
      set numFiles=1
   )
)
popd
```

Comment: Remove the first line, you will then see which line caused the message.

Comment: The moving of files part in the script is causing the syntax command error. But how will I modify it? Do you have any idea? Because the purpose is to move the processed files only from the input_path to the processed files path.

Comment: Sorry I am not familary with batch processing. You can modify the question to point out which line caused the error, the other people will provide better answers.

Comment: What is all that "!variable!"? What shall that do? Probably you meant to "%variable%"!? And what do you expect "!fileList: =!," to do?

Comment: @WernerHenze He has to use !variable! because he is in a for loop and uses the EnabledDelayedExpansion.

Comment: @user Are you sure all your file names do not contain any space characters? As it would break on the line `move !fileList: =,! "%proc_path%"`?

Comment: @modiX yes all of my file name do not contain any space characters. What does `move !fileList: =,! "%proc_path%"` mean?

Comment: @user It takes fileList, replaces all space with `,` and executes i.e. `move file1,file2,file3 path_to_move_files_to`. Then it moves all files to the path. If you did not know what this means, you did not code it, did you? You should do what user3767013 said.

Comment: You mean removing the first line? Yes already removed that and that's why I found out that the moving of files is causing the error. I tried to remove the `,` and there is no syntax error but the error now is `The system cannot find the file specified.` Do I need to remove the `!` after the `,`?Yes, I did not code it.

Comment: `set numFiles=0` and `set numFiles=1` should be `set /A numFiles=0` and `set /A numFiles=1` respectively; otherwise, the `if !numFiles! gtr 3` test fails

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out with the help of a friend. I just replaced this part of the script,

```
 set "fileList=!fileList:~0,-1!"
 move !fileList: =,! "%proc_path%"
```

with this,

```
for %%a in (!fileList!) do move %%a "%proc_path%"  >nul
```